# Automator and/or AppleScript to automatically Command-F2 to enter Target Display Mode

Tags: macos, applescript, imac, automator, target-display

I'm trying to use Automator with AppleScript to automatically hit Command + F2 to enter Target Display Mode. The script runs but I just get a beep/tone with no action. I don't know if there's an error in the script or if it's not capable of hitting a function key.

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "System Events"
        key down {command}
        keystroke "120"
        key up {command}
    end tell
return input
end run
```

Once I get this working I'll need to somehow schedule this to run on startup or maybe on a schedule. I've seen some threads on this but never an actual solution. I'm using a 2011 iMac as a secondary monitor and hate hitting Command + F2 every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keystroke "120"` is not the same as `key code 120`; the former taps the keys 1, 2, and 0.

I've had success with the following AppleScript, but you can also try key code 120 and [key code 113](https://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes).

```
tell application "System Events" to key code 144 using command down
```

Comment: That's awesome! Worked great. I converted the service to an application and set it to run as a login item. Thanks so much for the help!